# FFMPEG - Merging Video with Vignette-Only-Plate?

Tags: ffmpeg

Hello you beautiful people. I am currently figuring out how to use ffmpeg and asked myself a question. Usually, when using a vignette on a video, I would do the following:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf vignette=PI/4 output.mp4
```

This will obviously re-encode the video and thus I will lose quality. I could try using a lossless codec (such as libx264 with -crf 0 and -preset veryslow) and did so, but here's what I'm curious about:

Is it possible to create a Pass that only contains the vignette, to then merge the vignette plate with the video?

I would suspect that such a thing would be much less tedious for lossless vignetting, no?

Comment: *then merge the vignette plate with the video* --> as in combine with original video within a new file? Not possible.

Comment: No? Aw man that's too bad :(